# Proving a map/function based on two metric spaces is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $X \neq \emptyset$ be a set and $d$ the discrete metric on $X$. Let $(\Xi, \delta)$ be another metric space and $f : X → Ξ$ a map. How can I show that $f$ is continuous?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: By showing that the inverse image of an open set in weird symbol is open in $X$. (Note every subset of $X$ is open.)

Comment: Oh, it's a capital "xi".

Comment: Note that the discrete metric means that given a point $x$, there are no other points 'nearby' (as in the set of points $y$ satisfying $d(x,y) <1$ contains exactly one element, $x$). Hence it is trivial to 'be' continuous.

Comment: @DavidMitra Could you please show me a proof of this?

Comment: Perhaps it's best to use the metric space definitions, as in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's even uniformly continuous: for every $\varepsilon > 0$ and every $x$ we can pick $\delta = 1$. For if $d(x,x') < \delta = 1$, $x = x'$ by the definition of the discrete metric.... and so $\delta(f(x),f(x')) = 0 < \varepsilon$.